# Do only Gaudiyas use the term "expansion" and how does it relate to Vyuhas and Avataras?

Tags: vaishnavism, avatars, vyuha

https://bekrsnaconscious.blogspot.com/2018/10/lord-krishnas-expansions-and.html

Is there a single comprehensive doctrine regarding all the manifestations of the supreme Vaishnavite personal God?

Comment: This blog is based on Sri Laghu Bhagavatamrita by Srila Rupa Goswami. This is the most comprihensive presentation of Gaudiya Vaishnava understanding of 'expansions'. There is also an english translation along with Baladev Vidyabhushan's commentary online. https://archive.org/details/LaghuBhagavatamrta.VenkatesvarPress/mode/2up. The main teachings regarding expansions is found in Chaitanya Charitamrita as instructed by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu to Rupa Goswami.